# RSA.VerifyHash - разное поведение в Net.Core и Net.4.5

Tags: c#, .net-core

Переношу проект из net.4.5 в net.core.
Код net.4.5:

```
String RsaKey = "<RSAKeyValue><Modulus>vSf...EuQ==</Modulus><Exponent>AQAB</Exponent></RSAKeyValue>";
RSACryptoServiceProvider RSA = new 
System.Security.Cryptography.RSACryptoServiceProvider();
RSA.FromXmlString(RsaKey);
//Проверяем подпись
Boolean Res = RSA.VerifyHash(Hash, "MD5", Sign);
```

Код net.core:

```
RSACryptoServiceProvider RSA = new 
System.Security.Cryptography.RSACryptoServiceProvider();
RSAParameters parameters = new RSAParameters();
parameters.Modulus = Convert.FromBase64String("vSf...EuQ==");
parameters.Exponent = Convert.FromBase64String("AQAB");
RSA.ImportParameters(parameters)
//Проверяем подпись
Boolean Res = RSA.VerifyHash(Hash, "MD5", Sign);
```

В коде для net.core только загрузка ключа немного другое - нет процедуры загрузки ключа из XML.
Но код из net.core при проверке подписи возвращает Ложь, хотя все входные данные и ключи одни и те-же.
В чем может быть дело?

Comment: я не спец, просто уточню, там точно должно быть `Convert.FromBase64String`, а не какой нить `Encoding.GetBytes` ?. Просто вот это `AQAB` не позоже на base64

Comment: @tym32167 Это же фрагмент XML. А там бинарные данные стандартно через base64 кодируются...

Comment: @PavelMayorov я что то немного загнался, сорри. Надо перерывчик сделать :)

Comment: @Дмитрий, а если тот код который у вас для net.core написан, под net.4.5 запустить - что получится?

Comment: Попробуйте еще сделать в .net 4.5 ExportParameters и сравните с результатом Convert.FromBase64String

Comment: >Там точно должно быть Convert.FromBase64String<br/>
Да, параметры ключа создаются правильно<br/>

Comment: >а если тот код который у вас для net.core написан, под net.4.5 запустить - что получится? <br/>
Работает правильно!!!!!<br/>